# Random number generator in Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux

This is the code that i've written:

```
import os
import string
import random
def id_generator(size=8, chars=string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
b="echo " + id_generator() + "> file.txt"
os.system(100*b)
```

Now the problem is that when i run the script it returns one random number not 100.
I want that when i open **file.txt** it must be like:

```
123456
241721
126428
```

How can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get 100 random numbers you should call id_generator() function 100 times, but what you are trying to do is concatenate 100 times one already generated string.

Try this:

```
import string
import random

def id_generator(size=8, chars=string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in xrange(size))

random_numbers_string = '\n'.join(id_generator() for _ in xrange(100))

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(random_numbers_string)
```

Answer (score 5):

The redirection overwrites the previous contents of the file. You want `>>`, not `>`.

There is no need in using the obsolete `os.system()` and redirections here, by the way. You can do:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for _ in range(100):
       f.write(id_generator() + '\n')
```

This is also more cross-platform.

Comment: Just a note: opening with `w` (write mode) will truncate any existing file. Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for more info (and modes).

Comment: @thegrinner True, but the existing code truncates it 100 times one each execution, so creating a new file is probably desired.

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to make sure it was called out and avoid the confusion where running the script twice blows away the first 100 numbers :)